# How Can I Provide Dynamic Structure To AMP

Tags: amp-html, google-amp

I did publish a static structure AMP page, but I want to implement "Hotel Search" web page with AMP.How can i provide this dynamic structure with AMP ?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a sample of a specific page you want to move to AMP?
In order to implement a dynamic search, you could use [amp-form](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-form) together with [amp-bind](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-bind) for making the search dynamic (like showing or hiding some parts of the form based on previous input)